# "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1" Issue with $.parseJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am attempting to parse JSON text that is sent to the HTML page with the following code. I am receiving an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1" and I am unable to determine the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var irsDATA = [
{
'SSN': 'XXXXXX123',
'OPENDATE': '--/--/----',
'MAXCONTRIBUTION': '$500.00',
'CONTRIBUTIONYEAR': '2011'
}
];
var irsObject = $.parseJSON(irsDATA);
  $.each(irsObject, function(){
   $('#irsTable').append('<tr><td>'+this['SSN']+'</td><td>'+this['OPENDATE']+'</td></tr>');
  });
});
```

Comment: FYI: the `o` the parser is complaining about is the the second character in `[object Object]`

Comment: (On a side note, this is probably the 30th question I've seen like this in the last week.  I wonder why there are so many all of a sudden?  Maybe Stack Overflow has some new fancy algorithm that knows I always comment or answer this questions.)

Comment: @Brad - SO knows what you like :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`irsDATA` is already a plain JavaScript object; no need to try to parse it.

You're getting this error because `$.parseJSON` is meant to be called on a JSON **string**, such as `'[{"SSN":"XXXXXX123","OPENDATE":"--/--/----","MAXCONTRIBUTION":"$500.00","CONTRIBUTIONYEAR":"2011"}]'`.

Comment: I removed $.parseJSON and read irsDATA in the each loop and it works perfect. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As a complementary of answer below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var irsDATA = '[{ "SSN": "XXXXXX123", "OPENDATE": "--/--/----", "MAXCONTRIBUTION": "$500.00", "CONTRIBUTIONYEAR": "2011" } ]';
var irsObject = $.parseJSON(irsDATA);
  $.each(irsObject, function(){
   $('#irsTable').append('<tr><td>'+this['SSN']+'</td><td>'+this['OPENDATE']+'</td></tr>');
  });
});
```

here is an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/n5bm3GDk1a4pLIRgjfB1?p=preview)